# Pass a list of integers to JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

The below query is from a Spring boot application using JPA.
How do I pass in a list of integers in place of listOfFacilityIds?
Using a String does not work because facility_id column is an int column.
How do I pass an List of integers to the query?

````
@Query("select a from tableName a where a.date_of_contact BETWEEN :start AND :end AND facility_id IN :listOfFacilityIds")
    List<ModelName> findAllByFacilityAndDateCreated(
        @Param("listOfFacilityIds") String listOfFacilityIds,
        @Param("start") LocalDate start,
        @Param("end") LocalDate end);
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not passing List of integers in your param?

`@Param("listOfFacilityIds") List<Integer> listOfFacilityIds`

This should be pretty straight forward.